event.preventDefault() affecting further execution of code
There are 3 .ejs pages this project index.ejs, loading.ejs and result.ejs. index loads first and has the following code in its script tag:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      document.querySelector(".form-button").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "/loading";
        const response = await fetch("/submit", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },
          body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.querySelector(".form"))),
        });
      });
    });

This is the post request in the node-express server:
app.post("/submit", async (req, res) => {
  const form_link = req.body.form_link;
  const pythonProcess = await spawn("python", ["./py_scripts/script.py", form_link]);
  pythonProcess.on("exit", () => {
    console.log("Python script finished");
    res.redirect("/result");
  });
});

app.get("/result", (req, res) => {
  res.render("result.ejs");
});

The goal is to render the 'loading.ejs' file once the button is clicked until the Python script finishes executing. Once the Python script is done, 'result.ejs' is supposed to render.
The problem is that 'loading.ejs' is loading, but 'result.ejs' is not, even after the script is over. This is possibly beacuse of (my guess)'event.preventDefault()' affecting what was supposed to happen.
Is it possible to make express handle it instead of working it all out in the script tag of ejs files
I tried asking ChatGPT, claude.ai, Gemini but none of their solution seem to work

Once you navigate to a new page by changing window.location.href all scripts on the previous page stop running. The previous page's script can't redirect you anymore. The second issue is that res.redirect from Ajax call doesn't do what you expect it to do – it redirects the Ajax call, not the current web page the user is viewing.

Is there something else that can be done , i tried using two 'res.render()' in app.post("/submit") but that dosen't work because of the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error

The easiest way probably is to not have a separate "loading" page but some kind of overlay instead that you trigger with JS so that it doesn't navigate to a new page. Then after the Ajax call has finished navigate to the result page in the browser with window.location.href.

Note that if you want the form to post something to the server, so that the server can do something and redirect to a result page, that's what browsers naturally do when you post a form and you really don't need ajax at all.

Like @Pointy says. Redirecting to a new page defeats the purpose of a AJAX request. Consider just doing POST to /submit and then redirect to /result without any front-end JavaScript.

This issue is not caused by event.preventDefault();. Actually, I don't think that event.preventDefault(); has any effect in this callback function for a click event.
There are more issues in your code:

The window.location.href = "/loading"; is executed, and the page reloads. This happens before the AJAX (fetch) request is ever called.
In the post request handler on the back-end you create a redirect. But as it is now, the redirect will be on the response of the AJAX request. So, it will not redirect the user to /result.
Now, we haven't seen the the HTML form (I presume there is one), but my guess would be that the form still performs a request with the default method (GET) to the default action (same URL) aka. "GET index page". The browser does two requests, first the form submit (to /?form_link=...), and then to /loading.

Then, what to do? My guess is that you are not that experienced. So, I think you should remove the AJAX request and just do a plain POST request from the HTML form. You just need the following HTML form and the back-end code that you already did (and now the redirect to /result will work).
<form name="form01" method="POST" action="/submit">
  <input type="text" name="form_link">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

Alternative: Skip the extra request (first /submit, then /result). Rewrite the back-end, and do a POST directly to /result:
<form name="form01" method="POST" action="/result">
  <input type="text" name="form_link">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>

// POST request to /result
app.post("/result", async (req, res) => {
  const form_link = req.body.form_link;
  const pythonProcess = await spawn("python", ["./py_scripts/script.py", form_link]);
  pythonProcess.on("exit", () => {
    console.log("Python script finished");
    // render the result page
    res.render("result.ejs");
  });
});

// GET request to /result
app.get("/result", (req, res) => {
  res.render("result.ejs");
});

